# Solana Mainnet beta Validator Hardware

Tags: validator

I'm going to buy some hardware, CPU, RAM etc. to set my mainnet-beta validator node.

I know the requirements from [Solana docs](https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs), but I'm ignorant in hardware and I don't know which one is good.

So could you recommend manufactures, hardware models in detail or let me know which hardware you uses.

PS. I don't care about the cost!

Answer (score 2):

While you can buy the hardware and co-locate in someone else's datacenter, it is often much easier just to rent a bare metal server from an edge provider.

If you're unfamiliar with the process, the Solana Foundation has a program (https://solana.org/server-program) which can walk you through the process of picking your first server.

Personally, I rent from Equinix (https://www.equinix.com/), but Latitude (https://www.latitude.sh) is another popular provider chosen by many validator operators.

Answer (score 0):

Embora você possa comprar o hardware e co-localizar no datacenter de outra pessoa, geralmente é muito mais fácil alugar um servidor bare metal de um provedor de borda.

Se você não estiver familiarizado com o processo, a Fundação Solana possui um programa ( https://solana.org/server-program ) que pode orientá-lo no processo de escolha do seu primeiro servidor.

Pessoalmente, eu alugo da Equinix ( https://www.equinix.com/ ), mas o Latitude ( https://www.latitude.sh ) é outro provedor popular escolhido por muitos operadores de validação.

Comment: Please write your answer in english.